# How do I make a shortcut that types "o" when I I hit Alt+p?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

A few of my keys on my keyboard have stopped working after an accident. For the time being I want to know how I can remap these faulty keys to a shortcut. For example mapping "o" to Alt+p.

I have tried simply setting a shortcut with the command `echo "o"` but that doesn't work. I have also tried xmodmap but I can't seem to get it. Any help? Thanks!

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are on Xorg, `xmodmap` should be the appropriate tool. Alternatively, you can bind a command to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> that simulates hitting `o` using `xdotool`.

```
xdotool keyup alt keyup p type o
```

This first releases the hotkey you are pressing, then types an o.

Linux distributions, including Ubuntu, are moving to Wayland. Both tools do not anymore work on Wayland. The most fundamental way to adapt your keyboard layout, i.e., [editing kbe configuration files](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html.en), will continue to work but this is very complicated.